# What method to export various functions in node?

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I am building a database layer and am exposing your standard CRUD (Create, Read, Update, Delete) operations as functions. I'm toiling over which way to export each function.

### Method 1

```
function func1 () {}
function func2 () {}

module.exports = {
    "func1": func1,
    "func2": func2
}
```

### Method 2

```
var exporting;
exporting.func1 = function() {};
exporting.func2 = function() {};

module.exports = exporting;
```

or, to just do it directly:

```
module.exports.func1 = function() {};
module.exports.func2 = function() {};
```

### Method 3

```
export func1 = function() {}
export func2 = function() {}
```

I'm sure it wont break things on any method, but what are the pros and cons (if any) of each?

Comment: Very interesting exploration

Comment: According to [this article](https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-module-exports-exports-node-js/) there is no major differences.

Comment: I didn't think #3 would work unless you are transpiling your code, but it is the newer ES6 syntax and I tend to use that if I am running my code through Babel.

Comment: ES6 modules are not implemented yet on latest V8, so, there is no Node.js version that comes with it. Certainly is necessary babel with the preset `es2015`.

Comment: 1 and 2 is exactly the same, module.exports is just and empty object originally

Comment: You forgot `var exporting = {}` or `= module.exports`, otherwise your second method doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According with your examples, the example #1 and #2 are the same thing since `exports` is an object. You only are changing the way of add entries to this object.

This:

```
const object = {};
object.func1 = function () { return 'hello'; };
object.func2 = function () { return 'bye'; };
```

You can write like this:

```
const object = {
  func1: function () { return 'hello'; },
  func2: function () { return 'bye'; }
};
```

The last example owns to [ES2015 modules](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-modules) and is not implemented yet in V8 (in which Node.js runs). For this example you need the packages [babel](https://npmjs.com/package/babel) and [babel-preset-es2015](https://npmjs.com/package/babel-preset-es2015).

However, there is a important difference between using CommonJS and ES2015 modules:

> CommonJS modules export values, while ES6 modules export immutable bindings. That means: CommonJS export a **copy** of the module while ES2015 modules export a **reference** of it.

*See: [What do ES6 modules export? | 2ality.com](http://www.2ality.com/2015/07/es6-module-exports.html)*